# Row based access using ParquetSharp library in C# which is based on apache-parquet-cpp (Arrow)

Tags: c#, parquet, apache-arrow

Does anyone know how row based read access to a parquet file using `ParquetSharp` is performed? This is where I have got to but the `inputStream` throws an cannot convert to string error.

```
using (var buffer = new ResizableBuffer())
{
    using (var reader = new ParquetFileReader(@"C:\Users\X\Documents\X.parquet"))
    {
        using (var inputStream = new BufferReader(buffer))
        {
            using (var readerRow = ParquetFile.CreateRowReader<Tuple>(inputStream))
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also `ParquetSharp` uses `TTuple` but I cannot find any definition for it anywhere.

I know parquet is column based so this is not the most efficient method to read but it is convenient for my work.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

The row-oriented API of ParquetSharp uses reflection to discover the public fields of the given row structure or class. *TTuple* is just a generic parameter, a placeholder for the row type.

It works with custom structures or classes, System.Tuple and System.ValueTuple. You can see a few examples in https://github.com/G-Research/ParquetSharp/blob/master/csharp.test/TestRowOrientedParquetFile.cs

To take your example, you would define your expected row type:

```cs
internal struct MyStruct
{
    public readonly int FirstField;
    public readonly string SecondField;
}
```

And then somewhere in your method:

```
using (var reader = ParquetFile.CreateRowReader<MyStruct>(@"C:\Users\X\Documents\X.parquet"))
{
    /* read rows */
}
```

Although I personally prefer using C# 7 tuples, saving you the trouble to have to give your own struct definition in the first place. The only downside is when writing a Parquet file, ParquetSharp cannot automatically infer the column names from the field names (internally both System.Tuple and System.ValueTuple have got boring field names such as Item1, Item2, etc).

```
using (var reader = ParquetFile.CreateRowReader<(int firstField, string secondField)>(@"C:\Users\X\Documents\X.parquet"))
{
    /* read rows */
}
```